# DbContext Save: Access Custom Attribute

Tags: entity-framework

I have custom attribute define for each property of Models

```
[Auditable]
public class Student : BaseObject
{
    public Student()
        // Change this parameter to change the DisplayName 
        // (this name is used in all system messages)
        // property of this object
        : base("Student") { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Auditable(false)]
    public int OfficeAddressId { get; set; }
```

When you save the student record I want to check for the auditable properties and write them to the audittrack table. I want to do this in

```
    private void CurrentObjectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

can someone direct me to access the property with Auditable(false) and others against each entity.

Comment: can you explain more what you want? how you define the audittrack table? you mean you want to reflect this attributes in the CurrentObjectContext_SavingChanges function?

Comment: @ilay zeidman, Let's assume that there are business models in your BLL. I want to have an option to keep track of the (property value) changes you do to the properties of those models. As an example, there could be a model with the name 'student', then student may have several properties which I may not want to keep track of. But, let say that there is a property in the student model with the name "PaymentMade", which I *want* to keep a track of the changes made. I am expecting a solution for this. Continue...

Comment: In this sense, I am planning to mark the property with a custom attribute name [Audit(true)]. There could be other similar models that has similar needs in my BLL. So now when those objects are saving to the database, I want to track all of these models properties marked by audit attribute separately. This need to be tracked in the CurrentObjectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e) event and log the changes in to a separate table that maintain the audit trails. So the question is how you capture the model properties with Audit Attribute inside this event.. End!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this LINQ expression to get all properties of the `sender` annotated with the `Auditable` attribute (provided `IsAuditable` is property of the `Auditable` attribute, where the value from constructor is stored)

```
var auditableProperties = from p in sender.GetType().GetProperties()
    let attribute = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuditableAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as AuditableAttribute
    where attribute != null && attribute.IsAuditable == true
    select p;
```

The result of the expression is a collection of [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But it does not return anything but only an empty list. Are you sure that this does track the properties inside the entities that pass into the saving event??